# php mvc 'index' (not index.php) issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller

I'm getting started with MVC, trying to follow some examples I found that when a non existent controller in the url (i.e /catsanddogs) /catsanddos is catched via $_GET['url], but when the controler is index Apache sends "Not Found" error avoiding to get the url.

### my .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

### My index.php has

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
echo 'url:' . $url;
```

### Some output examples

URL: http://localhost/~mario/mvce/catsanddogs
---> url:catsanddogs

URL: http://localhost/~mario/mvce/index
---> Not Found

The requested URL /~mario/mvce/index was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

As 'catanddogs', 'index' doesn't exist as file, directory or link, Why this error is showing up? Is there something more to be done in apache conf or something like? Is there a way for this to be done from PHP (minimize use of htaccess)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your apache `DirectoryIndex` value set to? I wonder if this is catching it before it gets to your script

Comment: @AndyC could also be because of the relative URL ? `RewriteBase` might be worth noting too I reckon

Comment: @AndyC, DirectoryIndex is set to: DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm (in mods-available/dir.conf)

Comment: @Drren Do you think is something related to Apache config?

Comment: @Darren RewriteBase doesn't make a difference:

same result

Comment: Did you restart your apache instance after you made the changes?

Comment: Didn't do any change on Apache config, that's the default value for DirectoryIndex.

Comment: I must say that I'm running Linux Ubuntu 16.04, PHP7